# Object oriented programming concepts and resource management

Tags: c++

So I have a `FileReader` class, it looks like this:

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY(type) \
    type(const type&); \
    void operator=(const type&)

class FileReader { 
    FILE *file; 
    DISALLOW_COPY(FileReader);
protected:
    unsigned char *data; 
    long size;
public:
    FileReader(const char *filename);
    ~FileReader();
    unsigned long getSize();
    unsigned char *getFileData();
};


FileReader::FileReader(const char *filename) {

    file = NULL; data = NULL;
    if (!(file = fopen(filename, "rb"))) { throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened."); }
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    data = new unsigned char [size];
    VERIFY(size == (long)fread(data, 1, size, file));
    fclose(file);
#ifdef DEBUG
    PRINT("FileReader opening file "); printf("%s, %ld bytes.\n",filename,size);
#endif
}
FileReader::~FileReader() {
    delete[] data;
}
unsigned char *FileReader::getFileData() { return data; }
unsigned long FileReader::getSize() { return size; }
```

By itself it functions quite well.

When i create a `FileReader` I must do so with a filename that specifies what file it has to open, and when I am finished with it, it automatically cleans up after itself.

But I find I'm having a bit of trouble putting this class to good use. You see, if I try to use it from another class, for instance an `Image` class which represents a raster image, I'm not **always** creating an `Image` by reading it from a file. So, I don't want to inherit `FileReader` from `Image`.

Neither can I make `FileReader` a member of `Image`, because I still need to initialize (and read out a file) when I initialize my `Image`.

What I can do, however, is use `FileReader` in passing in `Image::loadFile()`, but then I must allocate a new buffer to store all the data, since `FileReader` will be cleaned up at the end of the function call.

At first I thought that RAII was a great idea, but now, I'm not so sure. It's great for handling exceptions, but I want to prevent having to move my data around like this, while keeping a clean interface that will help prevent memory management nightmares. Is there a way to do that? Seems to me like I have to significantly restructure things in order to avoid juggling all the data across a series of dynamically allocated buffers. Should I use smart pointers?

Comment: Why don't you build your object model based on the objects you have and their actions, and not based on one class you've already implemented and don't want to rebuild even though it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Are you sure you've understood the purpose of RAII?

Comment: if you going to move around pointers between different classes, its better to use smart pointers than raw pointers.That way you do not have to worry about deallocating the resources acquired by those pointers, the smart pointers will take care of that for you.

Comment: Blasphemy! RAII is a great idea, period.

Comment: @Als - exactly, smart pointer *are* an example of RAII just without reinventing the wheel as seems to be the case here

Comment: @littleadv, I wouldn't make something if I didn't at first think that it would suit my needs. The class seemed like a good concept at first. Now I'm trying to improve it. Yes I could start from scratch again (and it looks like I will) but I don't want it to end up just like this all over again.

Comment: Generally assignment is `type& operator=(const type&);` but then again I wouldn't use a macro for that purpose either. Actually I'd probably just use `std::fstream` instead of this entirely.

Comment: Ok I think a better way to phrase what I am looking for is "Will smart pointers help me make this code better, or is this all so crappy I have to start from scratch again?"

Comment: @AJG85 I will probably switch it to `std::fstream` and maybe `vector<char>`, but wouldn't it still end up doing many of the same things?

Comment: @Steven: Yes smart pointers would make it better but in this case I would use `std::vector<unsigned char> m_data` for similar effect.

Comment: @StevenLu - first try to do a design, then move to coding. Build a class diagram, with collaborations, inheritance trees and data flows. Then go on to coding. That will solve the need to redo the work already done.

Comment: Just a side note, in your `DISALLOW_COPY` macro, make sure you put `private:` also. Otherwise, if you put `DISALLOW_COPY` under `public:` by mistake, it could cause you problems

Comment: @TonyTheLion what exactly would you say is the purpose of RAII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly make `FileReader *` a private member and overload your constructor.

```
public:
    Image();
    Image(const char* fileName);
```

So, the consumer for your Image class decides what happens. In the second constructor you initialize your `FileReader *` and then destroy it in the destructor only if was initialized. I guess this might be RAII in the sense that the constructor on your object initializes which resource the object needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to put my C++ hat on ... I was thinking about FileReader pointer ... editted my post ...

Comment: Oh, okay, I see it now. That's actually a pretty clever way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

RAII **IS** a good idea. You need to split up your file and your "open file" objects. Make a new class called OpenFile, with a constructor like the following OpenFile(FileReader &f); Your resource is an open file, not the filename.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on this?